# border-radius + gradient + box-shadow causing ragged edge

Tags: css

When I apply border-radius and a background gradient to a `<li>` the rounded corners look ragged and rough. [Check it out on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCtgh/)

I'm seeing this in Chrome and FF. If I remove the gradient OR the border-radius the problem goes away.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I might fix it?

**UPDATE:**
I'm working on a jQuery solution that builds on Josh F's idea (see his full answer below). It's a simple jQuery function that appends a duplicate copy of the element behind it. At the moment, the scripts sets the positioning of the targeted element to `relative`. (I could see this being problematic in some cases.) My code is on jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkSeH/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current spec defines `box-shadow` to be drawn *outside* of the `border-box`. However, the background/border paints elements to the background, with no regard for other elements (it doesn't paint *with* objects, only on top of). Since the element with the `border-radius` is drawn before the `box-shadow`, it draws the corner with a semi-transparent edge to cause the corner to look smooth (as it should). Regrettably, due to how the spec is worded for `box-shadow`, it is drawn *after* the element, and therefore painted on top of the page (after the element) with a semi-transparent edge. Normally, this would be fine, but since both the element and the `box-shadow` have a transparent edge on the same pixels, it causes the small, semi-transparent gap.

This is a known bug, or has at least been considered a bug by the web design community. See [Bugzilla Bug #474386 (specifically comment #6)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=474386#c6) for source of my information.

Comment: Cool. Good to know. Do you know of any work-arounds (besides reverting to an image file background?)?

Comment: @Emerson, using an image file background would *not* solve the background. This is an issue with how the background itself is drawn, and isn't specific to gradients (see [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wCtgh/1/)). My typical workaround is to use a `box-shadow` and `background` that isn't *too* far off from the parent's `background`. While the transparent gap is still visible, it isn't as noticeable. Not ideal by any means, but it works. Another option would be to not use `border-radius` (as this is the main culprit).

Comment: Huh. I think I'm following what you're saying, but it looks like the gradient is also part of the problem. No? When I look at your jsFiddle (with flat background) on Chrome, the problem isn't there.

Comment: @Emerson, Chrome may handle background colors differently then (problem is visible in Firefox in that fiddle). I have a feeling background images would be treated the same as gradients though, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get around the bug would be to position a pseudo element behind the box that is 1px taller than the box and the same color as the box-shadow. This would hide the bug by making the previously white edge the same or close in color to the box-shadow.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farneman/e7TeV/) for an example.

Comment: Very clever. I was just thinking about trying something like that, but it hadn't occurred to me to use a pseudo-element.

Comment: That way you don't have to mess with the element's parent or add any additional markup.

Comment: I'm playing with this, and I've found one snag: I'm using `border-radius` all over my site, using several different classes. I'm realizing that I'm going to have to create a LOT of duplicate classes to apply the pseudo-element everywhere it needs to go because I can't think of a way to write the CSS in a way that it won't get really messy. In other words, I wish I could somehow mirror the parten's styles so the class can get reused: 
`.rounded-corners { /*border radius*/ }`
`.rounded-corners:after { /*border radius rules*/; width:[parent_width]; height:[parent_height]; ...}`

Comment: You could apply all the common styles as `.rounded-corners, .rounded-corners:after { /* common styles */ }` then provide the styles like background that are specific to each or override what you need to change for the `:after` in a second declaration. Also, using a css preparser like Sass or Less can provide helpers to make it more manageable.

Comment: That's what I'm going for, but I need to declare the width and height of "gap filler" pseudo-element. This is where it gets messy.